# subsequent printf statement ruining unrelated array

Tags: c, arrays, printf

In the following code, the printed result for char array `dir` is gibberish.
However, if I comment out the indicated `printf` statement, the printed result is intelligible. What is going on here? Thanks. sing code blocks / gcc.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char* handle_input(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char dir[200];
    printf("Number of arguments: %d\n",argc);

    if(argc<2) {
       printf("No argument specified\n");
       strcpy(dir,"Default argument");

    }
    else{
        printf("Command line directory was specified\n");
        ++argv;
        strcpy(dir,argv[0]);
    }

    strcat(dir,"_CAT");
    return dir;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    char* dir;
    dir = handle_input(argc,argv);
    printf("This one messes it up!\n");
    printf("%s\n",dir);
    printf("DONE\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `handle_input` function, you're returning a local array, which is a huge no-no; after the function ends, that array no longer exists, and what you return is just nonsense. This invokes undefined behavior later in your program. That `printf` call happens to overwrite the memory which previously belonged to the array. Without the `printf` call, that memory just happens to be intact, which is why it comes out intelligibly.

The right way to return an array is like this:

```
char* handle_input(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char* dir = malloc(200 * sizeof(char)); // sizeof unnecessary for char,
                                            // but it's a good habit to have
    printf("Number of arguments: %d\n",argc);

    if(argc<2) {
       printf("No argument specified\n");
       strcpy(dir,"Default argument");

    }
    else{
        printf("Command line directory was specified\n");
        ++argv;
        strcpy(dir,argv[0]); // This is unsafe! use strncpy instead
    }

    strcat(dir,"_CAT");
    return dir;
}
```

Using `malloc` ensures that the memory allocated will continue to exist after the end of the function, and that you will no longer be causing undefined behavior. Note that arrays are somewhat "special"; you can return primitive values (`int`, `char`, etc) and structs without having this sort of behavior occur.

Comment: Okay, Thanks!
I was intending to return a pointer to an array... where did I go wrong?

Comment: @ Chris thanks SOOO much :)
One thing you forgot but I figured out... the malloc needs to be recast as a (char*) here. 
Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyFouad If you're writing C casting malloc is unnecessary. If you're writing C++ you almost certainly shouldn't be using malloc (or printf, or raw C strings and the str* functions).

Comment: @Anthony: The reason you need to recast is probably because you forgot to `#include <stdlib.h>` (which I should have mentioned in my answer). If you do that, casting is not necessary.

Comment: @AnthonyFouad writing that cast causes undefined behaviour , if it would not compile without it. You should avoid "fixing" warnings/errors by casting, unless you are 100% sure you understand what is happening and there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a local `char dir[200]` in the function `handle_input`, after the function exits, it's undefined behavior to access it.

Use dynamic memory allocation instead, like:

```
char* handle_input(int argc,char *argv[]){
    char *dir = malloc(200);
    //do the processing
    return dir;
}
```

Remember to `free` it once it's out of use.

Comment: Thanks! One thing you forgot but I figured out... the malloc needs to be recast as a (char*) here. Thanks again!

Comment: @AnthonyFouad No, actually you shouldn't. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/1009479

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a local vasriable

Either

1. Use `malloc` (as you are in the C world with `printf`)
2. Pass in a pointer to be filled up